# What is a formal proof for Kutta-Joukowski Theorem in compressible flow?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics

Texts, such as *Drela*, Flight Vehicle Aerodynamics, indicate that the Kutta-Joukowski Theorem holds in compressible flow. Indeed, the KJT seems hold in linearized supersonic flow around a [2D flat plate](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/78819/does-an-airfoil-in-supersonic-flow-have-zero-circulation). However, the proof that I find on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kutta%E2%80%93Joukowski_theorem#Formal_derivation) relies on assuming that the flow is incompressible and that the total pressure remains constant.

Is there a formal proof that shows the KJT works in compressible flow, or supersonic flow where shock is present (across which total pressure changes)?